# Use of sha1 and md5 in integrity of package in yarn.lock

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, yarn-lock.json

Since md2, md5, sha1 hashing mechanisms are deprecated for iOS 13 and are not considered safe.

Why are we having it in integrity in dependencies in yarn.lock file.

```
"@types/redux-thunk@^2.1.0":
  version "2.1.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/redux-thunk/-/redux-thunk-2.1.0........"
  integrity sha1-vCtulylhgxr7gq.......
  dependencies:
    redux-thunk "*"
```

Is it safe to use for development?

Comment: As an aside, depending on the version of `redux-thunk` you're running, you shouldn't need that package – it's [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/redux-thunk)

Answer (score 0):

> Why are we having [SHA1] in integrity in dependencies in yarn.lock file.

Because not all packages have sha512 integrity hashes available. New(er) packages do, older packages might not.

> Is it safe to use for development?

Yes, I'd say so. I think it's very, *very* unlikely that anyone could concoct a malicious package file that would both be a valid package and have a SHA1 hash collision with the original.